# is the impersonation of this function possible?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum

Vaults[0] is a contract desingned to call this function, so I want to ask areas in which Vault[0] can be impersonated to call this function

```
        function mintForCommerce(address _to, uint256 amount) public 
           nonReentrant  returns (bool) {
           require(msg.sender == Vaults[0]);
           address to = _to;  
           require (amount >= 0);
           _mint(to, amount * 1e18);
           return true;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

For testing purposes, it is feasible to pretend to be the function's msg.sender (caller) in solidity.

If you have any more issues lemme know

Comment: Thanks for replying I'm trying to build a vault contract that handles funds

so, what security measures should I take to prevent the impersonation of the Vault[0] address?

Comment: is there a way around it

@Talha

Comment: can you share the rest of the code so i have a better understanding of the code so i can guide you better